# Insert new column at the end of the table containing concatenated values

Tags: excel, vba, new-operator

I have got a worksheet at work, I want to design a macro to insert a column at the end of a table to contain concatenated values of three columns within the table with a seperator (" - ") between them. So far, I have been able to insert the new column but not be able to concatenated values. My code is below, with added comments ....

```
Sub Demo()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim delim As String
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    delim = "-"
    With tbl
        .ListColumns.Add.Name = "CMRD"
        For Each cel In .ListColumns("CMRD").DataBodyRange.Cells
            With .DataBodyRange
                i = cel.Row - 1
                cel.Value = .Cells(i, 6) & delim & .Cells(i, 2) & delim & .Cells(i, 13)
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Edit: Solution verified - Code has been updated to reflect.

Comment: Welcome to so. ¿What is the fail? Not values at all? just in row 2? Can you focus? Anyways, your loop looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `Do While Cells(x, 28) <> ""` ?

Comment: so I am not able to concatenate the 3 values - at the moment i am running the code. I can insert the column at the end of the table but the cells remain blank. I have amended section you recommended accordingly but to no avail..

Comment: Execute your code step by step with F8 and check if your loop starts. Is `Cells(x, 28)` empty?

Comment: apologies, i didnt explain very well. My loop does not appear to start. there is no bugging issue. thanks

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can you confirm if  `AB2` is empty or not when this code executes? Maybe your loop should be `Until` instead of `While`

Comment: Hi, a friend of mine helped me complete the work. I have updated the code accordingly. thank you for your help.